# Get string from a space separated line in a file, given that lines leading string

Tags: batch-file

I have this `text.txt` file:

```
AAA = 111
BBB = 222
CCC = 333
DDD = 444
```

I am trying to assign as a variable, the value of the third space separated field relative to an existing first field, received as user input.

I tried the `findstr` utility, as below:

```bash
@echo off
set /P input=Input: 
>%TEMP%\foo.tmp findstr %input% text.txt
<%TEMP%\foo.tmp set /p var1=
echo Result is %var1%
pause
```

and have received:
`Result is AAA = 111`

But what I am trying to get is: when the user inputs `AAA`, I want the return to be the `111`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace lines `3` and `4` with: ```For /F "Tokens=3" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /BIL "%input%" "P:\athTo\text.txt" 2^>NUL') Do Set "var1=%%G"```.

Comment: I'd suggest `… /BIL /c:"%input% =" "P:\athT…` so that `AAAA = 123` is not detected. The `/c:` is required since the search-for string contains a space.

Answer (score 0):

Find string from file, and remove input string.
But result looks like "= Value", so I deleted first 2 characters.

It could be a better way, but this is my best.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P input=Input: 
set secondString= =
set target=%input%%secondString%

>%TEMP%\foo.tmp findstr /C:"%target%" text.txt
<%TEMP%\foo.tmp set /p var1=

set "replaced_var1=!var1:%target%!"
set "replaced_var1=!replaced_var1:~2!"

echo Result is %replaced_var1%
pause

endlocal
```

Result:

```
Input: AAA
Result is 111
```

Comment: Yes, I tested inputs of `BBB`, `CCC`, or something I added and it works well.